# Is there an online documentation repository for ruby like it is for Matlab? 

Tags: ruby, documentation

Is there an online documentation repository for ruby like it is for Matlab? A site that documents the functions and objects, their uses, parameters, etc?

[Matlab online Documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/f16-5872.html#f16-9856)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ruby-doc](http://ruby-doc.org)

1st result on Google. Seems well organized from what I saw.

Comment: *facepalm*, Thanks, i googled but i wasn't able to find anything...

Comment: [rubydoc.info](http://www.rubydoc.info/) is also very good